# How to make a summary starting from a particular row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know my question sounds simple, but I did not get along

I want to summarize a column, starting with a particular line containing a particular text, what is the appropriate formula for that?

```
sum(B1:B100)
```

But I do not want it to start from B1 just from a row that contains the text "start" in column A.
[image]

If my question already appears elsewhere, please write to me

Comment: Summarize how? You need to provide more details on this

Comment: I added a commentary

Comment: The line of the word "start" changes from time to time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&(MATCH("start",A:A,0))):B37)
```

The formula consist of the following three parts:

1st

By looking for the word "Start" in column A you get the row number where your sum formula should start. In the example row 7 will be the result.

```
MATCH("start",A:A,0)
```

2nd

The indirect formula creates a cell reference based on input. B is the column and row is the result from the match formula, in my example it gives the row 7.

```
INDIRECT("B"& (MATCH RESULT))):B37) -
```

3rd

We sum the range from the indirect to the end column we define by ourselves `(B37)`

`SUM(INDIRECT(column + MATCH row) end column and row)`

The result will be (sum starts from row 7 in column B):

[image]

Comment: You can even ditch one set of brackets, to get: `=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH("start",A:A,0)):B37)`

Comment: Thank you for the appropriate answer!, there are cases twice written "start" in the same column, how do I start from the last "start"

Comment: No problem :). use this: `=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&(SMALL(IF(A:A="Start",ROW(A:A)),2))):B37)` it will find you the row number for the second value (apply with Ctrl+Shift+Enter because it's an array formula). So if Start also exist in A10, this will sum from A10 and downwards.
`,2` shows that you want the second value it finds that match your search criteria.

Comment: @slomo: Nice thinking. I'll do some crazy VBA function on this one, with multiple possibilities. Coming up soon.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there is probably a better way to do this, but I got this working using two formulae.

First I assume you have an empty worksheet apart from:

- In column "A" there will be a single row with the word "start" in it;
- In column "B" there will be a whole load of numbers.

Add the following formula in cell D1: `=MATCH("start", A:A)`.  This will find you the row in column A with a "start" in it.

Add the following formula in cell D2: `=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&D1):B100)`.  This will sum from the row where start appears in B to B100.

Hope that gets you started!

Comment: Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: Well that's why I said there's probably a better way to do this :D  I don't think you can combine those into one formula, but I could be wrong.  I tried and gave up after a minute or two of experimentation.